JavaScript Playwright how do i write a test that ensures an action results in one server call and not infinite server calls
I am writing a JavaScript application and using Playwright to test my application.
I found a bug in my code such that on selecting an item in a list, my app got stuck in an infinite loop calling a server API.
The cause of this is that the user selects the item, a server call is made which returns an empty map and updates a variable with the result, when this variable changes we refresh the UI, as the map is empty we think we need to call the server to get the data, which again returns empty map and the loop continues. Therefore these server calls will always be sequential.  As the UI only updates when the data returns, there is nothing in the UI which is blocked, so I can't test any UI action, as the looping server call will not freeze/hold up the UI.
How can you write a playwright tests to ensure an action only causes a single server call.
Sample Code
I wait for the item to be visible using something like the following
await page.locator('list1','file1').waitFor();

Then I select and wait for the server request with code similar to below
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(resp => 
resp.url().includes('/myServerURL') && resp.status() === 200);
await page.locator('list1','file1').click();
const response = await responsePromise;

But i want to make sure that I only get one request to '/myServerURL' on selecting the item, and not more than one.
Is this possible in Playwright
Additional Context
Below is more details on the bug that was in my code that I am trying to write a test for to ensure I am not getting into an infinite loop in my code.

My app renders a list of items, when getting these items I get the permissions from the server and put in a map of itemId -> permissions.  If getting permissions fail, I returned an empty map.
When a user selects an item, the map is checked to see if it has the item's permissions. If it doesn't I make a server call to get permissions. If permissions are returned I add them to the existing map i have. If the permissions call fails, I do not add anything to the map, therefore the item is still not in the map.
This is where the infinite loop was happening. When the item is not in the map i get the permissions, when it fails i do not add the item to the map. So the item is never added to the map, causing future calls to get the permissions.
My fix was to add the failing item in the map with null/no permissions so we can tell the difference between the permissions never being asked for and the item having no permissions.

Although I have fixed this bug, I would like to have a Playwright tests, that ensures, when i select an item, i only have one call to get the permissions, and not stuck in a loop of trying to get the permissions.

You might be able to the use test.fail() in conjunction with two await responsePromise. The first await consumes the expected/valid call and the second await fails if there is no second call.

But in this scenario a hard wait followed by a check of the call number would be just as effective (i.e has a 2nd call happened within 1 second of the first call).

Thank you for your suggestions, I want to fail IF there is a second call. I.e. my action should only ever make 1 server call

My feeling is the the logic of the test is to capture the failure when waiting on the 2nd fetch.
To this end expect(promise).rejects.toThrow() looks like it takes the right direction, but I'm working to improve the timing.
Here's the test
test("Check for multiple fetch on click", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/one-fetch.html')

  const responsePromise1 = page.waitForRequest(resp => 
    resp.url().includes('jsonplaceholder') && resp.status() === 200
  )
  
  await page.locator("button").click()

  // consume the expected and valid fetch
  await responsePromise1;

  // look for a second fetch and expect it's promise to crash
  const responsePromise2 = page.waitForRequest(resp => 
    resp.url().includes('jsonplaceholder') && resp.status() === 200
  )
  expect(responsePromise2).rejects.toThrow()

})


My sample web page is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button>click</button>
    <script>
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('click')
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

        setTimeout(() => {
          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        }, 500)
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


This works and is probably better than my answer since waitForResponse is simpler than page.on, but will wait a full test timeout if the bug isn't present, which we assume will be the normal course of affairs, so I suggest clamping that time down, probably {timeout: 1000} on the waitForResponse. It's still a nasty test to write because that 1 second will permanently hurt CI time, so this still isn't a scalable test to use on a real application. Shortening the timeout increases the chance of false positives.

I don't think you can do anything different than wait for whatever time you think is the maximum - it's the "proving a negative" scenario, you can't say the 2nd fetch never happens, you have to say if it's going to happen it would be within 5 seconds and then wait that time to prove it. The same principle applies to the event handling approach you have, which is probably easier to understand since the steps are evident in the test (rather than relying on the internal behavior of page.waitForResponse which is not really designed for this).

My opinion is the test itself is valid and black-box, given that a complex app say Angular (with rxjs in the mix) has loosely coupled components that can cause regressions without an obvious reason.

Right, the problem is that 5 seconds of waiting isn't scalable in CI, and as mentioned, this is a surprising/unusual test to use in the first place. BTW, I recall now that the reason I switched to page.on is that waitForResponse/waitForRequest was somehow consuming 2 events in one if they're sync, so I would double check this to make sure it works when 2 requests are sent synchronously. Although OP used waitForResponse, I think waitForRequest is the correct condition here--faster and matches what they're actually trying to test (hitting a button sends 1 request).

Yes that's a good idea. I'm not really familiar with Playwright syntax, but it makes sense to wait on requests since that's what is being tested.

Follow up: confirmed this fails when 2 fetches are sent synchronously, so this doesn't generalize. Also resp.status() doesn't exist.

This is certainly possible:
import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.46.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<button>click</button>
<script>
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

  // remove this extra request to see the test pass
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
});
</script>
</body>`;

test("Only sends one request on button press", async ({page}) => {
  let requests = 0;
  const handleRequest = req => {
    if (req.method() === "GET" && req.url().includes("/users")) {
      requests++;
    }
  };

  await page.setContent(html);
  page.on("request", handleRequest);
  await page.locator("button").click();
  await setTimeout(100); // adjust to taste if there's async behavior
  await expect(() => expect(requests).toBe(1)).toPass({
    timeout: 1000,
  });
  page.off("request", handleRequest);
});

But I don't think this is a good idea. It's cumbersome to code (although you can write a helper function), and strikes me as overly paranoid. If other requests on the page to the same endpoint happen to trigger at the same time, you may see a false positive.
I'd focus more on the user experience than on network activity. There's probably a better way to verify this given more context. For example, to verify the app isn't frozen after the button click, try clicking something else and see if it takes effect.
That said, I suppose if you have an isolated case, you could use this once-off to help avoid regressions.
Note that since you haven't provided a reproducible case of this "button firing request multiple times" bug, I've made a best guess, and you'll likely need to adapt my code to match your actual application.
Note also that I use page.on because waitForRequest can swallow multiple requests, so I don't see that it's suitable for this particular use case.

The example would be better if the second fetch was on a setTimeout(). JS is single threaded, so here you get both fetches occurring before the test runs the expect(), but a framework might behave more asynchronously.

That's mostly on OP--the question is already quite vague about what exactly this bug is, and OP hasn't provided a [mcve] of the target site under test. So I made a common-case guess. If you check the edit history, there's a version with a sleep, or one could use an expect(...).toPass() with a slight timeout. Feel free to add a sleep or a timeout depending on the actual case at hand, otherwise, it's unreasonable to expect that this sort of thing can be easily written to handle all frameworks off the shelf without sleeping, which isn't necessary in all cases.

But you already pointed out the use-case - to test for regressions.

Not cover all regressions, just a reasonable subset of them. Let's say you click a button, then there's a bug where 30 seconds later, more requests are inadvertently fired off. I'm not attempting to testing that and nobody can reasonably expect to test that--it'll clog CI at the best case scenario, sleeping like that. It's more reasonable to assume OP is sending both requests off more or less synchronously.

I have another option using expect().rejects.toThrow(). It doesn't feel complete, but I'll post it anyway since it's in the direction I think this should go.

Go for it, but the point here is that these are weird tests to want to write, I've never felt the need to use such a thing in a real app, and how you actually test this sort of thing is not to cover every possible case ever, because that's impossible, but to code up a specific check for the specific use case or framework, with my example being one plausible case. Likely an XY problem. What sort of bug would occur where a button sent multiple requests? Ideally, I'd like to see an example of that first.

Upvoting as the better approach because it's more obvious and there's no way to avoid the hard wait period. Except 100ms is probably not going to be enough.

100ms should be OK if you're testing requests rather than responses, and they're fired reasonably quickly, as I'd imagine them to be. You want that period to be as low as possible to avoid sluggish tests, which are a serious problem in PW for any large app. (I repsonded similarly in the other thread, apologies for the somewhat overlapping conversations)

Depend entirely on the app structure.

Thank you for your feedback, its really helpful. And yes its a weird test and very specific use case and not one I would write normally.  The server requests are made async so it does not hold up the UI so I cant use actions in the UI to verify its not stuck,   I think your solution here will probably work for this specific case, thank you
